# about detecting if a number is odd or even in javascript

Tags: javascript

I am working on a tutorial for JS on CodeAcademy and I am asked to create a function to check if the input is divisible by 2.

Here is my code:

```
var isEven = function(number) {

  if (number % 2 ===0) {
    return true;
  }
  else if (!isNaN(number)) {
    return "Give a number";
  }
  else {
    return false;
  }
};
```

Why does codeacademy tell me that the code is wrong because the function will result in true for 3?

Comment: three is not NaN, so the function will return "Give a number"

Comment: Well, `3` is not even, so it seems correct to say that your function is incorrect. Or is your question *why* your function returns `true` for `3`? In that case, set a breakpoint your code and step through it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In JavaScript, anything that is not ["falsy"](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Falsy) is true. So, your string "Give a number" is considered to be true.

Comment: Get rid of the condition where you check for isNan and just return true or false.

Comment: tutorial asks me to check if input is number at all  and if its not to return a string asking for number....

Comment: @AggelosSfakianos: So your function incorrectly treats `3` as not a number.

Comment: The other posters are right about your condition on isNaN (you are saying if it is not not a number), I was too quick to jump to a more complicated answer :)

Comment: Thank you for marking my post as an answer but you should probably mark one of the people who actually had the right answer :)

Answer (score 2):

!isNaN(3)  -> evaluates to true

```
if (typeof(number) === "number"){
  return (number%2 === 0)
} else {
  //do something else 
  return false
}
```

Comment: also note if input is given as a string such as "2", this will return false

Answer (score 1):

Reverse your sign on !isNaN i.e. remove the exclamation point - needs to be negative in construct

But really you shouldn't be returning text either.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
var isEven = function(number) {

 if (!isNaN(number)) {
  return "Give a number";
 }

 else if (number % 2 ===0) {
  return true;
 }

 else {
  return false;


    }
};
```

Comment: same problem...Oops, try again. Your function returns true for 3! is what comes up...